# Change antd variables at runtime with craco

Tags: reactjs, antd, craco, react-app-rewired, customize-cra

I have to be able to change ant design variables at runtime (not via theme less files).
I've found plenty of examples of this using **customize-cra** and **react-app-rewire-less**, but none seem to work with craco. I have to use craco because I'm also using **tailwindcss** in this project.

What I've tried:

- **[antd-theme-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-theme-webpack-plugin)**: I have access to `window.less.modifyVars`, but it seems to do nothing (calling it throws no errors, but the antd colors don't change);
- **[antd-theme-switcher](https://github.com/conroychee/antd-theme-switch)**: Very similar to the above, `window.less.modifyVars` seems to have no effect;
- **[antd-theme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-theme)**: I could not figure out how to add the `AntdThemePlugin.loader` in `craco.config.js`, and I'm not sure that is the problem, but I could not make it work.

This is the current state of my `craco.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");
const CracoAntDesignPlugin = require("craco-antd");

const AntDesignThemePlugin = require("antd-theme-webpack-plugin");
const options = {
  antDir: path.join(__dirname, "./node_modules/antd"),
  stylesDir: path.join(__dirname, "./src"),
  varFile: path.join(__dirname, "./src/styles/variables.less"),
  themeVariables: ["@primary-color"],
  indexFileName: false,
  generateOnce: false,
};
const ThemePlugin = new AntDesignThemePlugin(options);

module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAntDesignPlugin,
      options: {
        customizeThemeLessPath: path.join(
          __dirname,
          "./src/styles/variables.less"
        ),
        lessLoaderOptions: {
          lessOptions: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
            modifyVars: {
              "@primary-color": "#00375B",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    { plugin: ThemePlugin },
  ],
};
```

At this point I'm up to try any possible solutions really, this problem has been really time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today I got it working. The second solution ([antd-theme-switcher](https://github.com/conroychee/antd-theme-switch)) actually worked as intended. My error is that I was adding the antd default variables in my main less file, but for this to work I had to add the color.less file in my public folder (as the second step in antd-theme-switcher says), so that `window.less.modifyVars` has a less file to work in.

This seem to be not the most performatic approach though, and I'm going to bail from using antd in my project as soon as I can, as there seems to be no optimal solution for changing variables at runtime with this specific setup.